# Calculated Column with Nested IF statments

Tags: calculated-column

Here is my current formula that works.

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([Project Close A]="",IF(Program="CAPITAL",IF([Project Close P]>=[Current Date],"green","red")),IF([Project Close P]>=[Project Close A],"green","red"))&";'>•</DIV>"
```

I now need to add an additional IF statement that states if Project Cloase P is blank turn yellow.  When I add If([Project Close P]="", "yellow" to the front of the above it doesn't work.  How do I fix this?

Comment: How about showing what you tried - you've likely made an error like a missing , or ) but without putting what you tried there is no way to know.

Comment: Also what field type is Project Close A - is it a date?

Comment: Here is what I've tried. ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([Project Close P]="","yellow",IF([Project Close A]="",IF(Program="CAPITAL",IF([Project Close P]>=[Current Date],"green","red")),IF([Project Close P]>=[Project Close A],"green","red"))&";'>•</DIV>")  Yes Project Close A are date fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing a closing bracket at the end

```
IF([Project Close P]="","yellow",IF([Project Close A]="",IF(Program="CAPITAL",IF([Project Close P]>=[Current Date],"green","red")),IF([Project Close P]>=[Project Close A],"green","red"))
```

Should be

```
IF([Project Close P]="","yellow",IF([Project Close A]="",IF(Program="CAPITAL",IF([Project Close P]>=[Current Date],"green","red")),IF([Project Close P]>=[Project Close A],"green","red")))
```

Get yourself a decent text editor like Notepad ++ and it will highlight matching pairs of brackets making it really easy to spot things like this.

Comment: I get an error that the formula contains a syntax error or is not supported when I add the )

Comment: It works when I remove the script in the front of the formula and at the end.  But I need this script to add the colored dots.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I removed an If statement and added the If([Project Status P]="", ""white" and removed a ) in the middle of the nest and addit to the end.  So @Ryan I was missing a ), Thanks!  Here is the final formula and I attached a picture just in case someone wanted to see.  ="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([Project Close P]="","white",IF([Project Close A]="",IF([Project Close P]>=[Current Date],"green","red"),IF([Project Close P]>=[Project Close A],"green","red")))&";'>•</DIV>"![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXMS.jpg