# Help with 'IF' Statement for Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I need help writing an IF statement for a SP calculated column. I have it working right now to display the green indicator, but need to add the clauses for it to display the yellow and red indicators as well.

```
="<DIV><imgsrc='"&IF(Colour="Green","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF")&"'></DIV>"
```

The first section (green status) is what is working, the rest needs modification I know. Basically I want to add :

IF Colour="Red" then display "/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF"

IF Colour="Yellow" then display "/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF"

PLEASE help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep nesting the if statements,

```
="<DIV><imgsrc='"&IF(Colour="Green","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF",&IF(Colour="Red","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF",&IF(Colour="Yellow","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF")))&"'></DIV>"
```

The syntax above might not be perfect, but you should get the idea

Comment: What is wrong with my syntax, i am getting errors? ="<DIV><img
src='"&IF(Colour="Green","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF"),"&IF(Colour="Yellow","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF"),"&IF(Colour="Red","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF")&"'></DIV>"

Comment: Hurray, I got it, thanks to you and this other thread : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/calculated-column-with-nested-if-statments?rq=1.  Thank you therefore to Trisha and Ryan as well.

Comment: ="<DIV><img
src='"&IF(Colour="Green","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF",IF(Colour="Yellow","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF",IF(Colour="Red","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF")))&"'></DIV>"

Comment: I am not sure but have a look here [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/da4f3e45-5f84-4332-9d90-20dad08fb25c/calculated-columns?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)