# Calculated Column Formula - Nested IF Statements

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

Im new to formulas,

My issue is i want to display the current location of said item and keep the old locations so for now i have three columns Location1 Location2 and Location3 and i want to have a calculated column called "current location" showing whichever is the latest location,

for example if column2 is blank then show column 1 and if column 3 is blank then show column 2.

Comment: So did you get the calculated column to work?

Answer (score 0):

Hi SPistotallyawesome,

[This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/calculated-column-with-nested-if-statments) deals with nest IF statements in a calculated column; they are fiddly to begin with.

As Ryan mentions in his answer, download Notepad++ - it's free and it has a cool chameleon icon, what more could you want!

If you need some more examples to study browse through the [Calculated Column Tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcalculated-column%5D%20IF) to see related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column 2]),[Column 1],IF(ISBLANK([Column 3]),[Column 2]))
```