# Sharepoint list - if a value is submitted twice or more - show the amount of entries in a different column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, auto-increment

I'm working with MS Flow / Form and I'm trying to show the amount of time a single user submits something into Sharepoint. (see below)

[image: Example of output]

Is this possible through a formula?]

Thanks.

Comment: I've just posted an answer, but read your question again.  I'm not sure what you mean by increment / auto-increment...

Comment: I want it to show the number of times the same value was submitted - incrementing in a different column.

Comment: Please see updated Answer

Comment: Hi Michael S, I updated my Answer, did you get this to work??

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count the number of items with the same email address?  I might have misunderstood your question...

A really quick answer might be to create a view, then use the `Group By` setting - group by email address.  This groups all items submitted from an email address and totals up the number of items they've submitted:

So if test@test.com has submitted 5, it would look like this:

test@test.com (5)

While if another email address submitted 3, it'd look like this:

test2@test2.com (3)

Like I said, a quick answer, but maybe you have reasons for needing a calculation/formula.

**Updated - following your comments**

In which case you can use a calculated column - see MS [guidance here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

[image]

So in your case you'd make a new calculated column and adapt the formula to fit your column names - call the new column `CountEmail`.

Microsoft example:
=IF([Column1]="Vietzen", "OK", "Not OK")

Your example:
=IF([Email Address]="test@test.com", "1", "0")

The `CountEmail` column will show a 1 in the 5 items with the `test@test.com` email address.

Next you need to find a way of counting all the "1" values in the `CountEmail` column.

[image: countemail screen shot]

So, I've got you part way.  However, I believe you'll need to use a 'nested IF statement' in your calculated column, which is more complicated.  It's more complicated because you have more variables in your calculation - you want the calculation to be able to handle values x, y and z (x, y and z = the different email addresses.  Please [see here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/calculated-column-with-nested-if-statments) for an example of a nested IF statement.

Comment: I want another column to show the number of entries so I can refer back to it in MS Flow to help with a report.

Unless it is possible to skip the 'test@test.com' and only bring back '(3)' or '(5)' etc

Comment: Another way to do this would be to use variables - I've not used Flow, but if it is similar to the way Sharepoint Designer works, you can use variables in a workflow to count the number of e.g. test@test.com values.  Your variable would be the email address, it would count the email and paste this value in to an EmailCount field.